# Find minimum in i-j range less than in O(j-i) using less than O(N^2) memory

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory, minimum

Say there is a big array that containes N integers:

```
const unsigned N = 1e12;
int array[N] = { 1, 3 , 8, -5, 4, 3, -1 -6, 6, ....., N};
```

There should be queried many times the smallest element in the range of different `i` `j` indecies. THe complexity of returning the minimum should be smaller than in O(j-i) and the problem should be solved using less than O(N^2) memory.

How this can be done?

Comment: The number of ranges of the type (i,j) are in fact O(n<sup>2</sup>), so how can it be possible to get the minimum for all (i,j) ranges in less than that?

Comment: This problem is named [Range Minimum Query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query). You can find several possible solutions in "External links" of corresponding Wikipedia page.

Comment: You can be askek for 30 ranges only. And aswers shoud be returned nat by doing linear number of steps for the given ranges.

Comment: Evgeny, the problem is really called RMQ, but wikipedia page does not help me. Therefore I am here.

Comment: Would putting the elements in a `std::set` not help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static array, as you mentioned, the fastest solution is O(1) with O(n) preproc. But in practice you may want to use one of the following approaches, which also work for dynamic arrays, and seem to me easier to understand and code:

1. divide the array into sqrt(n) sections, each with sqrt(n) elements, and store minimums for each of those segments. Each (i,j) will contain some of those segments entirely plus maybe some elements from left and right. Pass over these elements and stored answers for segments to find the min. This requires O(n) preproc, O(sqrt(n)) query, O(sqrt(n)) update and O(sqrt(n)) memory. Also very easy to code.
2. build a [minumum segment tree](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree) over the array. This gives O(logn) for query/update, O(n) memory/preproc.

Comment: Բոցն են ա, որ բացի քեզանից Շատախն էլ ա պատասխանել վերևում (aram90):

Answer (score 3):

RMQ works in the following way:

We keep an array M[N][logN], where M[i][j] shows minimum number of range starting from i and having length 2^j. To fill that array, at first we calculate all M[i][0] values, which are all equal M[i][0] = A[i] (A[i] is the original array). After that, by induction each M[i][j] will be equal to **min(M[i][j - 1], M[i + (1 << (j - 1))][j - 1])** i.e. we get values for longer intervals by taking minimum of its left & right parts, which should be calculated in previous step as we are going from shortest to longest intervals.

After that, to get minimum value in [a..b] interval, you need to find the biggest P, such that 2^P doesn't exceeds the length of interval [a..b]. And the answer will be **min(M[a][P], M[b - (1 << P) + 1][P])**

Answer (score 1):

For those who knows Russian this is the solution: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/rmq
For those who don't know Russian, sorry, I have not found something. If someone will find, please edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a 2D array where an entry [i, j] stores the minimum value in range arr[i..j]. Minimum of a given range can now be calculated in O(1) time, but preprocessing takes O(n^2) time. Also, this approach needs O(n^2) extra space which may become huge for large input arrays.

Another solution is to construct a Segment tree.Segment tree can be used to do preprocessing and query in moderate time. With segment tree, preprocessing time is O(n) and time to for range minimum query is O(Logn). The extra space required is O(n) to store the segment tree.

Representation of Segment trees

1. Leaf Nodes are the elements of the input array.
2. Each internal node represents minimum of all leaves under it.

The construction of the Segment tree is explained in detail here:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/